# NUnit my extension doesn't load

Tags: nunit

I wrote an extension for NUnit 2.6.2.

I install a listener like

```
namespace NUnit.EventExtension
{

[NUnitAddin(Type = ExtensionType.Core)]
public class NUnitExtension : IAddin
{
    public bool Install(IExtensionHost host)
    {
        IExtensionPoint listeners = host.GetExtensionPoint("EventListeners");
        listeners.Install(new AttrHooksEventListener());
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

The AttrHooksEventListener is a simple class when I output some text to the console.
The project is builded success. I copy my dll file to bin\addins path. But my extension isn't showed in list of extensions and doesn't work.

PS I tried to use some other sample extensions, anyone from them doesn't work.

Whiy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

I olny changed the target .NET framework version from v4.0 to v3.5.